# Make seekbar function and play mp3 file in java

Tags: java, mp3, audio-player, seekbar

My friends and I are making an mp3 music player project. But when it comes to making functions like the seekbar used to show the time of the song, clicking to rewind, or playing mp3 files, there are problems... how do I do the above?
Libraries I added: jlayer 1.0.1, mp3spi, jaudiotagger, tritonus-share

```
public class MP3Player {
    public static String filepath = "E:\\MusicDB\\\\Exil - Hiboky.mp3";
    private AdvancedPlayer player;
    private int duration;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, CannotReadException, TagException, ReadOnlyFileException, InvalidAudioFrameException, JavaLayerException {
        MP3Player mp3Player = new MP3Player();
        mp3Player.initPlayer(filepath);
        mp3Player.play();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MP3 Player");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 150);

        JProgressBar seekbar = new JProgressBar(0, mp3Player.getDuration());
        JLabel currentTimeLabel = new JLabel("Current Time: 0:00");

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(seekbar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(currentTimeLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        seekbar.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                int currentTime = seekbar.getValue();
                long minutes = currentTime / 60;
                long seconds = (currentTime % 60);
                currentTimeLabel.setText("Current Time: " + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds)+"/"+minutes+"/"+seconds);
            }
        });

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int currentTime = seekbar.getValue() + 1;
                if (currentTime <= mp3Player.getDuration()) {
                    seekbar.setValue(currentTime);
                    long minutes = currentTime / 60;
                    long seconds = (currentTime % 60);
                    currentTimeLabel.setText("Current Time: " + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        seekbar.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                int mouseX = evt.getX();
                int newTime = (int) ((double) mouseX / seekbar.getWidth() * seekbar.getMaximum());
                seekbar.setValue(newTime);
                try {
                    mp3Player.seek(newTime);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MP3Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (BitstreamException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MP3Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MP3Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initPlayer(String filePath) throws JavaLayerException, CannotReadException, IOException, TagException, ReadOnlyFileException, InvalidAudioFrameException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.jaudiotagger").setLevel(Level.OFF);

        AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
        duration = audioFile.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength();

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        player = new AdvancedPlayer(fileInputStream);
    }

    public void play() {
        Thread playerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                player.setPlayBackListener(new PlaybackListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void playbackFinished(PlaybackEvent evt) {
                        // Handle playback finished event if needed
                    }
                });
                player.play();
            } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        playerThread.start();
    }

    public void seek(int time) throws FileNotFoundException, BitstreamException, JavaLayerException {
    int frame = time * 1000; // Convert seconds to milliseconds
    Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(new FileInputStream(new File(filepath)));
    int totalFrames = (int) bitstream.readFrame().max_number_of_frames(bitstream.readFrame().max_number_of_frames(-1));
    double percentage = (double) time / duration;
    int framesToSkip = (int) (totalFrames * percentage);

    // Close the player and create a new one with skipped frames
    player.close();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
    player = new AdvancedPlayer(fileInputStream);
    
    // Skip frames
    for (int i = 0; i < framesToSkip; i++) {
        if (!player.play(1)) {
            break; // Break if unable to play more frames
        }
    }
    
    // Start playing from the skipped position
    play();
}

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
}
```

-method to get song duration and display seekbar position works properly
-But the tap to fast forward feature doesn't work on Jlayer
-I want to switch to Clip playback and get the error: No line matching interface Clip supporting format MPEG1L3 48000.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, stereo, unknown frame size, 41.666668 frames/second is supported.

Comment: as far as I'm aware, JLayer doesn't provide the option to pause or to use a progressbar